# Cluster Analysis: Problem finding Euclidean distances of centroids in a dataframe from origin

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cluster-analysis, euclidean-distance

The 7 columns for each row in df_centroids show the coordinates in a 7 dimensional space.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import scipy
```

```
df_centroids

        0           1           2           3           4            5          6
0   2.443664    -0.158806   -0.403137   0.609063    -0.412371   -0.486611   -0.687598
1   -0.389052   1.258986    -0.517471   -0.127748   0.379712    -0.486611   -0.143564
2   -0.215555   0.201088    1.149816    -0.501471   0.275600    -0.088475   1.434132
3   -0.227075   -0.806379   -0.412111   -0.174150   -0.417327   -0.401676   -0.234962
4   -0.130615   0.197548    1.282325    -0.940454   0.161774    2.167632    -0.263252
5   0.015202    -0.125552   -0.665733   1.792274    -0.360096   -0.390093   -0.044649
```

I'm trying to calculate the Euclidean distance from origin and save it under 'Euclidean Distance' column. Please see code below:

```
df_centroids['Euclidean Distance']=''
from scipy.spatial import distance

i=0
while i<len(df_centroids.index):
    centroid=[df_centroids.iloc[i,0], df_centroids.iloc[i,1], df_centroids.iloc[i,2], df_centroids.iloc[i,3], df_centroids.iloc[i,4], df_centroids.iloc[i,5], df_centroids.iloc[i,6]]
    df_centroids[i,7]=distance.euclidean([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], centroid)
    i+=1
df_centroids

       0            1          2          3             4           5           6      'Euclidean Distance'     (0, 7)      (1, 7)       (2, 7)       (3, 7)      (4, 7)     (5, 7)      (6, 7)      (7, 7)
0   2.443664    -0.158806   -0.403137   0.609063    -0.412371   -0.486611   -0.687598                       2.722099    1.556305    1.949607    1.136964    2.716432    1.988787    7.161965    6.851439
1   -0.389052   1.258986    -0.517471   -0.127748   0.379712    -0.486611   -0.143564                       2.722099    1.556305    1.949607    1.136964    2.716432    1.988787    7.161965    6.851439
2   -0.215555   0.201088    1.149816    -0.501471   0.275600    -0.088475   1.434132                        2.722099    1.556305    1.949607    1.136964    2.716432    1.988787    7.161965    6.851439
3   -0.227075   -0.806379   -0.412111   -0.174150   -0.417327   -0.401676   -0.234962                       2.722099    1.556305    1.949607    1.136964    2.716432    1.988787    7.161965    6.851439
4   -0.130615   0.197548    1.282325    -0.940454   0.161774    2.167632    -0.263252                       2.722099    1.556305    1.949607    1.136964    2.716432    1.988787    7.161965    6.851439
5   0.015202    -0.125552   -0.665733   1.792274    -0.360096   -0.390093   -0.044649                       2.722099    1.556305    1.949607    1.136964    2.716432    1.988787    7.161965    6.851439
6   0.256554    1.422368    1.139299    -0.917565   6.804388    -0.486611   0.726889                        2.722099    1.556305    1.949607    1.136964    2.716432    1.988787    7.161965    6.851439
7   6.010360    0.643581    2.401293    -1.193860   0.068166    1.636784    0.726889                        2.722099    1.556305    1.949607    1.136964    2.716432    1.988787    7.161965    6.851439
```

As you see, instead of calculating Euclidean space, the code is creating 8 new columns and copying the same set of values for all rows. Where am I going wrong?

I have tried looking up online for a solution but no luck so far. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Note, instead of listing the 7 coordinates, you could just write `df_centroids.iloc[i,0:7]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with `numpy`, you usually never have to use loops. Highly tuned vector and matrix operations exist for most use cases.

For your problem, note that the Euclidean distance to the origin is the same as the Euclidean norm. There is a [function in `numpy.linalg`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) for that.

To calculate the Euclidean (l-2) norm of one vector:

```
import np
np.linalg.norm([1, 2, 3])
# 3.7416573867739413
```

To calculate the norm for a matrix of *row vectors* individually for each row (as in your problem):

```
np.linalg.norm([[1,2,3],
                [4,5,6]], axis=1)
# array([3.74165739, 8.77496439])
```

To calculate the norm for a matrix of *column vectors* individually for each column:

```
np.linalg.norm([[1, 4],
                [2, 5],
                [3, 6]], axis=0)
# array([3.74165739, 8.77496439])
```

Comment: Thanks for helping with this and sharing additional use cases. Appreciate it.

Comment: My pleasure! If you end up having to calculate distances to somwehere else than the origin, be sure to check out [`pdist()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist).

Answer (score 2):

In your code you are missing .iloc, should be:

```py
df.iloc[i, 7]
```

instead of:

```py
df[i, 7]
```

To avoid such mistakes i would do this using apply:

```py
sample = {'a': [2, 2, 3],'b': [3, 5, 2], 'c': [3, 6, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(sample)
origin = [0,0,0]
df['distance'] = df.apply(lambda x: distance.euclidean(origin, x), axis=1)
print(df)
>>>     a   b   c   distance
>>> 0   2   3   3   4.690416
>>> 1   2   5   6   8.062258
>>> 2   3   2   2   4.123106
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the omission. Good idea on using lambda function instead. Appreciate it.